# I can't redownload an older version of an app, which holds my music library locally. How do I get my data back?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id, storage

I usually listen to my music on an app called Nhaccuatui. I tried to update it recently, from version 5.x to 6.x. After updating 2 icons appeared on the screen. One works fine and is empty, the other I can't open anymore. I deleted all two from settings, keeping the old version's data only. I then tried to reinstall the old one, but it seems that the developer removed that version 5.x from appstore. Reinstalling from the appstore's purchased menu didn't help, plus there was no popup asking to install the old version. Is there anything I can do to restore the mp3 files?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @nohillside sorry, I assumed everyone knows I need my data back is what I'm trying at

Comment: Ask the developer for a copy of the older version?

Comment: Where you not able to restore the deleted app from the Trash?

Comment: @bretonics I'm using Iphone 6s, ios 14. I don't think there's a trash app

Comment: Ooos, sorry, missed the tag. Thought it was a Mac. I think the only way is if you had a backup on a computer